# The "Storage Space Running Out" notification in status bar will nothide or delete

Tags: applications

I tried the common answer I see here. I long-pressed the notification, then chose "App Info". It comes up as the "Android System", version 4.4.4 (old!) but the "Force Stop", "Disable" and "Show Notifications" box, which is checked, are all greyed out and I cannot change them. Can I hide the notification? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot block notifications from "Android System". Later versions of Android (i.e. Android 9 (Pie)) allow blocking of categories of notifications, but for your case the easiest solution is to either get used to it or attempt to free up space on your device. I wish you good luck!